# DialogResult box default to No?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
DialogResult result;
result = MessageBox.Show(breakpl[0], "Move this to confige file?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

All I want is for when the box pops up to default to No, there is around 1000 No's and like 10 yes's.  So I just want to be able to hit enter and cycle threw them.

Comment: I presume you mean the WinForms MessageBox, not the C# MessageBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MessageBox.Show() overload that takes a MessageBoxDefaultButton argument.  Or just invert the question.

Comment: You will confuse the user with a message like that.  But the vast majority of them will click No when they don't understand what's being asked.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload on MessageBox.Show() to accomplish this.  You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335426(v=VS.71).aspx)